# Define Lambda policy and assume role policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm writing a Lambda function that should be triggered (after `X` amount of time) using a CloudWatch event. I have almost the configuration working, but I can't get the policy business from AWS right. This is what I have so far:

```yaml
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    principals {
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }
  }
  statement {
    actions   = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "this" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
  role       = aws_iam_role.this.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json
  name               = "AWSLambdaSpringCloudFunctionBasicExecutionRole"
}
```

> I just want the Lambda to be able to write to CloudWatch and be triggered by the CloudWatch Event source...that's all, no more permissions. I'm creating the Log Group via Terraform, so no need for `logs:CreateLogGroup`.

When I do `terraform apply` (version `0.12.24`) this error pops out:

```sh
aws_iam_role.this: Creating...

Error: Error creating IAM Role AWSLambdaSpringCloudFunctionBasicExecutionRole: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
    status code: 400, request id: 12ad676e-b98e-4c60-bedd-bf17487bd51d
```

Is there a way to declare the AWS Lambda policy and assume role policy together? If not, what are the recommended Terraform resources/data sources for doing this?

---

**UPDATE:** Complete Solution

As Oleksii pointed out, I was using the wrong resource to create the IAM policy:

```yaml
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    principals {
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "assume_role" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
  name               = "Use Any Identifier/Name You Want Here For IAM Role"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "logs" {
  statement {
    actions   = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "logs" {
  name       = "Use Any Identifier/Name You Want Here For IAM Policy Logs"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.logs.arn
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.lambda.name]
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "logs" {
  name   = "Use Any Identifier/Name You Want Here For IAM Policy Logs"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.logs.json
}
```

Comment: Did you miss `effect: "Allow"` on second statement?

Comment: Updated...I do have it, forgot to type it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to define multiple statements in `assume_role_policy`, which is not a regular policy, but a "trust relation" type of policy. It only describes who can assume role and under which conditions.

From my understanding (limited Terraform knowledge) you need to move second statement to its own policy and then attach it via `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`

Comment: Just found about it; was missing the combo: `aws_iam_policy_document`, `aws_iam_policy_attachment`, and `aws_iam_policy`...that's what I have to defined (and work) with the second one I was trying to stick on the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`.